Connect to own api based on booking ID
We are investigating the openai API for building a support desk.  Is it possible to add some kind of routes based on keywords in dialog ?  By example when user asked a question about their booking we call our own endpoint API (not openai)  to fetch the status of the booking ?
Best remco

Make your prompts in this format -


const query = "The weather is hot";
const prompt = `Reply with the word "true" in the response for the prompt if the prompt contains booking related query else return false. ${query} - GPT replies?`;

const query2 = "My confirmation for the trip is not showing on the app";
const prompt2 = `Reply with the word "true" in the response for the prompt if the prompt contains booking related query else return false. ${query2} - GPT replies?`;



The response should contain the words "true" or "booking". Based on open ai's response you can then redirect.
Another method is to create a local bag of words model where you put all the booking-related words in a map and check if the query contains any of the terms.
Your prompt call with the former method should cost about 15 tokens approx.

is this the simple trick todo this? thanks!

You can simply ask the user if their query is booking-related and provide them two choices, yes or no. That would be the simplest solution.
